# Unable to publish SharePoint Info-path for based on content type

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, form, publishing

I have one form library with one content type and info-path form attached to content type. I have republished the info-path form to form library instead of site content type so it cause the duplicate column in it. Now I am not able to publish the info-path form.

Also , Info-Path shows the error window that to is not readable as below.
[image]